# Adding OneSignal to detached expo react native project does not build in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, expo, onesignal

I have a react native app, detached from expo that has worked.
I am trying to add OneSignal to the project, and following this doc:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

I am building this with android studio.

This is my gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }

      dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
      }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    android {
      compileSdkVersion 26
      buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

      defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.startach.yedidim.volunteers.detached'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName '2.0.1'
        ndk {
          abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
        manifestPlaceholders = [
          'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
        ]
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'MY-APP-ID.....',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
      }
      dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
      }
      productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
          // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
          // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
          // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
          minSdkVersion 21
        }
        devRemoteKernel {
          minSdkVersion 21
        }
        dev19 {
          // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
          // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
          minSdkVersion 19
        }
        prod {
          // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
          minSdkVersion 19
        }
      }
      buildTypes {
        debug {
          debuggable true
        }
        release {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          zipAlignEnabled true
        }
      }
      signingConfigs {
        debug {
          storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
        }
      }
      lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
      }
    }

    // Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
    // crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
    // locale-specific date functions are called.
    // configurations.all {
    //   resolutionStrategy {
    //     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
    //   }
    // }


    task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
      workingDir '../'
      if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
      } else {
        commandLine './detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
      }
    }
    preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep


    dependencies {
        compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

      // Our dependencies
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

      // Our dependencies from ExpoView
      // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
      compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
      }
      provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
      compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
      compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
      compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
      compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
      apt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
      compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
      compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
      compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
      compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
      debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
      // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
      releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
      compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
      compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
      compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
      compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
      compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
      compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
      compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
      compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
      compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
      compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
      compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
      compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'
      compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
        transitive = false
      }
      compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

      // Testing
      androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
      // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
      androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
      androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
      androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
      androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
      androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'



      compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:25.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
      }


    }

    // This has to be down here for some reason
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Edit: In the manifest I only changed what the docs asked:

```
.....

<!-- Optional - Add the necessary permissions (Choose one of those) -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <!-- Approximate location - If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <!--  Precise location If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->

<!-- End optional permissions -->

<application ....>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTop"> <!-- Add this parameter -->
    .....
```

Getting this error when trying to sync gradle:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-onesignal'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.evaluateProjectAndDiscoverTasks(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.beforeResolvingProjectDependency(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.beforeResolved(DefaultProjectDependency.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencies(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencyDescriptors(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.addConfigurations(DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultConfiguration.java:682)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$DefaultResolveContextToComponentResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:129)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:443)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:436)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:436)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:411)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:484)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveConfiguration(DependencyManager.java:354)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:281)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:166)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:375)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createVariantData$3(VariantManager.java:607)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:603)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:793)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:487)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:263)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureFully(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchyFully(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.forceFullConfiguration(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:87)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:136)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:671)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:570)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    ... 148 more
```

Comment: Did you also modify your `Manifest`?

Comment: I updated the question